# On deploy, Heroku says it can't find API key even though I've logged in

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

When I run `heroku deploy:jar app.jar --app app`, I receive this error:

```
$ heroku deploy:jar build/libs/app.jar --app app
Uploading app.jar
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: app
       - including: build/libs/app.jar
 ! ERROR: Could not get API key! Please install the toolbelt and login with `heroku login` or set the HEROKU_API_KEY environment variable.
 !        Re-run with HEROKU_DEBUG=1 for more info.
 ▸    There was a problem deploying to app.
 ▸    Make sure you have permission to deploy by running: heroku apps:info -a app
```

Here's there environment's information:

```
On a Mac.
Heroku version: heroku-cli/6.16.12 (darwin-x64) node-v9.11.1
Heroku plugins: heroku-cli-deploy 0.4.0
java version "1.8.0_131"
node version: v4.9.1
```

I've tried running `heroku login` multiple times.  After it's run, I can run `heroku apps:info -a app` and it lists the information.  I'm inferring that that means I'm logged in already.

My login works on another computer, so I assume it's a local config issue and not an account issue.  When I set `HEROKU_DEBUG=1`, it provides no additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lay in `heroku login`. It creates a file `~/.netrc` containing your login and token.

The format of this generated file on another mac (the mac I mentioned the deploy was working fine) was as follows:

```
machine api.heroku.com
  password ...
  login ...
machine git.heroku.com
  password ...
  login ...
```

The format of the same generated file on the mac which was giving the above problem was as follows:

```
machine api.heroku.com login ... password ...
machine git.heroku.com login ... password ...
```

Apparently, both formats are fine for most Heroku commands such as viewing apps and such. But for the `deploy` command (which requires the `heroku-cli-deploy` plugin, only the first format is acceptable.

So basically the heroku cli accepts both new lines and spaces as delimiters between the endpoint, login, and token. But the deploy plugin only accepts new lines. `heroku login` was using spaces for some reason; so heroku commands were working, while the heroku deploy commands were not.

Comment: awesome. i'll try it out on Monday when I have access to the machine again. If you don't mind pointing me in the right direction, i was curious to look at the fix, but couldn't find any relevant changes to the heroku git

Answer (score 0):

There would be another reason for the same error in Ubuntu. For some reason in Ubuntu it is easy to make jhipster cli installation that requires sudo while heroku cli don't allow to log in under sudo because browser start doesn't work from the sudo call. And it is uneasy to figure out, what was wrong with jhipster sudo installation, which particular files now owned by the root and so on.

But if you have logged to heroku cli not from the root user (i.e not using sudo) or created api key variable not from root user (i.e not using sudo) your deploy will fail with the error above if you'll request jhipster with sudo:

```
sudo hipster heroku
```

if you'll try it without sudo, it will hang on

```
Installing Heroku CLI deployment plugin
```

To make it working just run

```
sudo -E jhipster heroku
```

and -E will pass your api key variable to the sudo execution